# Selenium Java - This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting the Following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
```

While using this Version of Chromedriver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.20/

This is how I manage the Dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-alpha-4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", SeleniumConsts.CHROMEDRIVER);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I get the exception on the second line
The Consts

```
public static final String CHROMEDRIVER = "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
```

I don't have any system variables regarding chromedrive. if I start my script a chrome instance starts but the program crashes
so I guess I used the right pathing
and because I don't use system variables it should be the only chromedrive version on my pc

I also tried to close my "main use" google chrome but it didn't change anything

full exception:

> "C:\Users\KNG HOLDY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\201.4865.12\jbr\bin\java.exe" ""-javaagent:C:\Users\KNG HOLDY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\201.4865.12\lib\idea_rt.jar=56986:C:\Users\KNG HOLDY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\201.4865.12\bin"" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ""C:\repos\LeagueRegistrator\target\classes;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-api-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-chrome-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service-annotations\1.0-rc6\auto-service-annotations-1.0-rc6.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service\1.0-rc6\auto-service-1.0-rc6.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\auto\auto-common\0.10\auto-common-0.10.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\28.2-jre\guava-28.2-jre.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\2.10.0\checker-qual-2.10.0.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.3.4\error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chromium-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-chromium-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-devtools-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-http\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-http-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-json\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-json-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-edge-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edgehtml-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-edgehtml-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-firefox-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-ie-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-opera-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-remote-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\4.3.0\okhttp-4.3.0.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\2.4.1\okio-2.4.1.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.50\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.61\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.61.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\typesafe\netty\netty-reactive-streams\2.0.4\netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.43.Final\netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.43.Final\netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.43.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.43.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.43.Final\netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.43.Final\netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\opentracing\opentracing-api\0.33.0\opentracing-api-0.33.0.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.6\byte-buddy-1.10.6.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client\2.10.4\async-http-client-2.10.4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client-netty-utils\2.10.4\async-http-client-netty-utils-2.10.4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.42.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.42.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.42.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.42.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.42.Final-linux-x86_64.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.42.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.42.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.42.Final-osx-x86_64.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver-dns\4.1.42.Final\netty-resolver-dns-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.42.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-dns\4.1.42.Final\netty-codec-dns-4.1.42.Final.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\javax.activation\1.2.0\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-safari-driver-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar;
> C:\Users\KNG HOLDY.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\4.0.0-alpha-4\selenium-support-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar"" org.example.App
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.20 (f006328e39a9769596eb506c8841c3004b24e747-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#244}) on port 16033
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
> Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-4', revision: 'c2d955b49e'
> System info: host: 'DESKTOP-89KMETV', ip: '192.168.178.55', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.6'
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
> remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
> Ordinal0 [0x00805D53+2448723]
> Ordinal0 [0x00738131+1605937]
> Ordinal0 [0x0062F879+522361]
> Ordinal0 [0x005C05F3+67059]
> Ordinal0 [0x005BCD92+52626]
> Ordinal0 [0x005DC127+180519]
> Ordinal0 [0x005DBF2D+180013]
> Ordinal0 [0x005D9E5B+171611]
> Ordinal0 [0x005C1DD8+73176]
> Ordinal0 [0x005C2E50+77392]
> Ordinal0 [0x005C2DE9+77289]
> Ordinal0 [0x0074D6A7+1693351]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x008A3E16+522726]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x008A3B54+522020]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x008B8F67+609079]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x008A4686+524886]
> Ordinal0 [0x00745A8C+1661580]
> Ordinal0 [0x0074F00B+1699851]
> Ordinal0 [0x0074F173+1700211]
> Ordinal0 [0x00764FE5+1789925]
> BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74E76359+25]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775B7B74+228]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775B7B44+180]

```
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$1(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:15)
```

Comment: What version has your Chrome Browser?

Comment: The major versions of chromedriver and your Chrome browser need to match exactly. Check your chrome version and your driver version

Comment: my "main" chrome is Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit) (it says its up2date)
but the driver i downloaded was 81.*

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/ Use this chrome driver instead

Comment: I have same problem, my chrome is 80.0.3987.122 and my chrome driver is 80.0.3987.106

Answer (score 0):

Probably as college said reason why you are getting this issue, is because you have a different version of selenium chrome driver and Chrome browser. Chromedriver and Chrome browser has to have always the same version number.

In the past, I had a lot of trouble with this issue but recently I found this great dependency: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

It is taking care of your chrome driver and you don't' need to think about the version.